# set the content of a frame from different page - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a frame called `mainFrame` which is inside `MainWindows`. I have a page called `page1`, when the app starts, I dynamically set the content of the `mainFrame` to `page1`.

Now, suppose I have another page called `page2`. I have a button inside `page1`, I want When I click on that button, `mainFrame`'s content changes to `page2`, But I can't access `mainFrame` from `page1` .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you need to get current instance of your MainWindows.

Inside your click event handler for button in Page1 write :

```
MainWindows objMainWindows = (MainWindows)Window.GetWindow(this);
objMainWindows.mainFrame.Navigate(Page2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'NavigationService' instance is available from the page.

```cs
// Inside page1
private void ClickEventHandler()
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(page2);
}
```

Or if you want to return control flow to the mainwindow before changing the page, look into `PageFunction`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Sajith Sageer answer:

1. This also works

   `objMainWindows.mainFrame.Content = new Page2();`
2. To disable `ugly navigation arrows` add into `<Frame>`

   `NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35655621)